# Do I need to use fetch() to get a Parse.com query?

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and changing a simple local database setup to a Parse.com class adapting a link saver from this repo: https://github.com/peterjmag/reading-list

I want to switch the fetch call for the native to parse .save()

Can I use the fetch or should I rewrite the function to use the parse.com language?

Adding the link is declared on this

```
LinkActions.addLink.listen(function (link) {
    fetch('//localhost:3001/links/', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    url: link.url
  })
})
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error('Bad response from server');
        LinkActions.addLink.failed(link);
    }

    return response.json();

    }).then(function (newLinkData) {
        LinkActions.addLink.completed(link, newLinkData);
    });
});
```

EDIT

The new code looks something like this:

OK. So my new code looks something like this now.

```
    LinkActions.addLink.listen(function(link) {

        var LinkListing = Parse.Object.extend("LinkListing");
        var linkListing = new LinkListing();

        linkListing.save({
            url: link.url
        }, {
            success: function(linkListing) {
                // The object was saved successfully.
            },
            error: function(linkListing, error) {
                // The save failed.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            }
        });
    });
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either keep the `fetch` and use the parse.com [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide), or refactor your code to use the [Javascript API](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide), icnluding functions such as `save`. I recommend refactoring to the Javascript API because it would make your code much shorter and clearer.

For example, two things which definitely shouldn't be your concern are adding  headers to every request and comparing every response status to 400.

Comment: It actually helped a lot.